# How do I find an order that contains all the available products?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **products** table that contains all the available products, as well as the **order_has_product** table which contains all the products that should be included in every order.

How do I find the **order_id** for any order that contains all the available products?

*Note how the order with an **order_id** of 1 contains all the available products.*

**order_has_product:**

| order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |

**products:**

| product_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | shovel |
| 8 | rake |
| 9 | scythe |

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM order_has_product
WHERE product_id = ALL (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM products
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way by using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT order_id FROM order_has_product 
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_id)=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_id) FROM products)
ORDER BY product_id;
```

This query compares the concatenated product id's which will check if an id contains all the product_id's listed in the products table.

**RESULT**

```
order_id  
----------
         1
```

> MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group

Check [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) for more details and examples of `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! I will read up on `GROUP_CONCAT` to make sure I understand it fully. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> `ALL` means that the condition will be true only if the operation is true for all values in the range.

so that `ALL =` might not you expect, but we can try to use `>=` which will match with the biggest product_id of `order_has_product`.

```
SELECT order_id
FROM order_has_product
WHERE product_id >= ALL (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM products
);
```

otherwise, If I understand correctly from your logic, we can try to use `EXISTS`  subquery to make it.

```
SELECT ohp.order_id
FROM (
  SELECT order_id,COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) cnt
  FROM order_has_product ohp
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products p WHERE p.product_id = ohp.product_id)
  GROUP BY order_id
) ohp
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM products p    
   HAVING COUNT(*) = ohp.cnt
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=68aa5e724efd888ff15b852040536af6)

Answer (score 0):

If by ***How do I find the order_id for any order that contains all the available products*** you meant to find the individual order_id which buys everything in your products table (in other words, big spender order_id), others have provided you with answers. However, if you want to find whether an individual order_id has a product_id that is not in the products table(in other words, whether or not has everything ready to ship), I can help.

```
create table order_has_product (order_id int,product_id int);
insert order_has_product values(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(2,7),(3,8);
create table products (product_id int,name varchar(10));
insert products values(7,'shovel'),(9,'scythe'); -- order_id 8 is removed from the table for better demonstration

select order_id,
min(if(product_id in (select product_id from products),'yes','no')) as has_everything_ready 
from order_has_product
group by order_id 
;
```